# Pop-Up Window at inital start up, of android application

Tags: android, popup, window, changelog

I am trying to find a code that will do a popup at the initial start up on an installed app. Much like a changelog that is starting to appear in more and more apps. 
I have found some similar codes, but being a beginner I haven't been able to figure out where to exactly put the code in and I always have tons of errors that still do not work once I try and fix them.
I am working in Eclipse with an android project, and I'm using a webview to show a website.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">



<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java File:

```
package com.A2Ddesigners.WhatThe;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.view.KeyEvent;


public class Whatthe extends Activity {
    WebView webview;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setInitialScale(50); 
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); 
        webview.loadUrl("http://mdsitest2.com/");
    }
    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;


            }

            }   
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using My this code you can show popup on any type of view on intial time of activity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

public class PopupDispaly extends Activity {
    private PopupWindow outComePopup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tiwter_login);
        final View anyView = findViewById(R.id.popo_up); // define heade your view
        anyView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                callFirstToolTip(anyView);
            }
        }, 5000); // hear you can put your delay time like 5000 mls

    }
    public void callFirstToolTip(View view) {
        Log.i("Started Info","popup");
        View layout = LayoutInflater.from(PopupDispaly.this).inflate(R.layout.popup_copy_delete, null); // define hear your layout file id.
        LinearLayout layCopyDelete = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.layCopyDelete);// hear define your id of sub lay like LinearLayout.
        outComePopup = new PopupWindow(layout);
        outComePopup.setFocusable(true);
        layCopyDelete.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        outComePopup.setWidth(layCopyDelete.getMeasuredWidth());
        outComePopup.setHeight(layCopyDelete.getMeasuredHeight());
        outComePopup.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));
        outComePopup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        outComePopup.showAsDropDown(view);
    }

}
```

And my Custome View layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/got_it_bg"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:id="@+id/layCopyDelete"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Thank for appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should use a custom dialog box. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

There's a code example at the bottom of the page. To show it, you can call onCreateDialog(int) from inside your main activity in its onCreate() method.

Comment: I've tried that and I've not been able to get it to work, much less get it to work only during the first time an app starts up. I'll try it a few more times.

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this?

Answer (score 0):

`PopupWindow.showAsDropDown()` in a delayed process can solve this problem, you can execute the show `popupWindow` in `onCreate()` method by 0.5s delay.

Comment: Using a delay does not always guarantee the desired result as you can't predict how slow the device your app runs on. It's better to use `post` method of the view

Answer (score 0):

You should use `PopupWindow.showAtLocation` but use the `post` method of the one of the views on your activity. you can also use the root view of the activity using `findViewById(android.R.id.content)`.
You code should look like this:

```
View anyView = findViewById(R.id.anyView);
anyView.post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // Create and show PopupWindow
    }
});
```